# Getting a list of entries in a group. MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a table which just generates Project ids. `project_table`, which has the `project_id` and other columns.

I have another table `project_members` which has 2 columns `project_id` which is the `FOREIGN KEY` to `project_table` and a `user_id` column.

I want to know whether a set of users (passed as a comma separated value) fall in the same `project_id`.

For example - 
The `project_members` table has the following entries

```
project_id user_id
         1       1
         1       2
         2       3
         2       4
         2       1
```

When i pass `id's` `1,2` i want to know which `project_id` these users come in. Also the condition is that only `ids 1 and 2` should be in that project.

So the input and output for the above data should be -

```
input output
1,2        1
1,2,3   NONE
1,3,4      2
1,2,4   NONE.
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT   project_id
FROM     project_members
WHERE    user_id IN (1,3,4)
GROUP BY project_id
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 3
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e27e1/1/0).

Note that this assumes there are no duplicate `(project_id, user_id)` records in `project_members`.  If there are duplicates, you will need to use the more expensive [`COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct) instead of [`COUNT(*)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count).

---

If you must perform this operation within a stored procedure, you could use MySQL's [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function in place of the `IN` operator and calculate the count from the total [`CHAR_LENGTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) less the length of the input string with all its commas removed:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_projects(IN members TEXT)
SELECT   project_id
FROM     project_members
WHERE    FIND_IN_SET(user_id, members)
GROUP BY project_id
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1 + CHAR_LENGTH(members)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(members,',',''));
```

Note that this assumes that `members` contains *distinct* `user_id` values separated by commas and no other padding or superfluous content.

---

To find the projects for which contain the exact members specified, one can instead do:

```
SELECT   project_id
FROM     project_members
GROUP BY project_id
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 3
     AND NOT SUM(user_id NOT IN (1,3,4))
```

The procedural version would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_projects(IN members TEXT)
SELECT   project_id
FROM     project_members
GROUP BY project_id
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1 + CHAR_LENGTH(members)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(members,',',''))
     AND NOT SUM(FIND_IN_SET(user_id, members)=0);
```

Comment: The problem is 1. I am passing the ids as csv in a variable which MySQL, for some reason, does not understand. 2. How do i get the count.

Comment: @Juniad: Both of those problems can be most readily solved within the application code that dispatches the query.  In what language is your application developed?

Comment: I pass the csv of ids to a stored procedure. The application is in Java.

Comment: Thank you. I have a small problem now. If i have a project id 1 with users 1,2,3, the query returns project id 1 if i pass 1,2 only. I want to get the project id only if the project contains all the ids in the csv. Is it possible?

Comment: @Juniad: Okay, see my revised answer above and this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a06e8/1/0).